# eml_scalexp_subsref missing Matlab 2014a OS X 10.10

Tags: matlab, undefined, osx-yosemite

I'm doing a Friedman stats test in MATLAB 2014a on OS X 10.10.

I'm getting:
'Undefined function 'eml_scalexp_subsref' for input arguments of type 'double'.'

And sure enough... I can't find this file on my machine in any toolbox.

Installation is fine and pretty much every stats function I've tried runs well.

I'm guessing it's an OS X issue.
Anyone else having this?

Comment: Edit your question to show code and any inputs you give it that causes the issue so we can try to replicate or at least know what you're talking about. Also, please provide the full error message including line numbers. Why do you think that this is an OS X issue?

Comment: I believe it was a result of BCILAB toolbox or one of its dependencies. I installed a stable version of BCILAB and this solved it!